# clipboard.js Copy text in side closest <pre>

Tags: javascript, clipboard

I am using [clipboard js](https://clipboardjs.com/)

I would like to be able to copy my `<pre>` content but not sure how to make it work with the code inside bootstrap panel

Here is example what I have tried [codepen](http://codepen.io/riwakawebsitedesigns/pen/rrxEyQ)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var clipboard = new Clipboard('#copy-button');

    clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
        console.info('Action:', e.action);
        console.info('Text:', e.text);
        console.info('Trigger:', e.trigger);

        e.clearSelection();
    });

    clipboard.on('error', function(e) {
        console.error('Action:', e.action);
        console.error('Trigger:', e.trigger);
    });
});
    
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">

<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
<div class="clearfix">
<div class="pull-left"> 
</div>
<div class="pull-right">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="copy-button">Copy</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-body">
<pre>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /projectFolder/index.php/$1 [L]  
</pre>
</div>
</div>
</div><!-- Panel--> 
</div>
</div><!-- Row -->

</div>
```

### Solution

Thanks to [@Natrium](https://stackoverflow.com/users/59119/natrium) working

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
<div class="clearfix">
<div class="pull-left"> 
</div>
<div class="pull-right">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="copy-button" data-clipboard-target="#foo">Copy</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-body">
<pre id="foo">
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /projectFolder/index.php/$1 [L]  
</pre>
</div>
</div>
</div><!-- Panel--> 
</div>
</div><!-- Row -->
```

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var clipboard = new Clipboard('#copy-button');

    clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
        console.info('Action:', e.action);
        console.info('Text:', e.text);
        console.info('Trigger:', e.trigger);

        e.clearSelection();
    });

    clipboard.on('error', function(e) {
        console.error('Action:', e.action);
        console.error('Trigger:', e.trigger);
    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the documentation on https://clipboardjs.com/.

Your button needs an attribute `data-clipboard-target` where you specify a selector to the element you want to copy.